# Hadoop MapReduce wordcount tutorial error: Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting an error when running the basic Hadoop wordcout tutorial in eclipse on my Cloudera VM. The error is:

```
Input path does not exist: file:/user/cloudera/wordcount/input
```

However, this directory *does* exist, I've specifically created it and I'm staring at it in my HDFS file browser.

[Screenshot of my command line query and browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGGte.png)

I have copy pasted the directory from the command you see into my run configuration in eclipse, these are my arguments:

```
/user/cloudera/wordcount/input /user/cloudera/wordcount/output
```

And the code itself has not been modified from the example I downloaded, the relevant lines are:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

***Edit:***

```
hadoop jar /home/cloudera/examples/wordcount.jar WordCount /user/cloudera/wordcount/input /user/cloudera/wordcount/output
```

This command *works* in the terminal, but when I execute the java file that I built that jar from (no changes, just export->jar file) with the arguments "/user/cloudera/wordcount/input /user/cloudera/wordcount/output" then I get the above error.

Why won't eclipse run this task properly? It works from the terminal.

Comment: Can you show the execution of hadoop commands?

Comment: you can refer few example on http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in/

Comment: `file:/user/` is different from `hdfs:///user/`. That is probably where your confusion is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why won't eclipse run this task properly?

I assume you are giving `/user/cloudera/wordcount/input` as `args[0]` to Eclipse?

This will create `new Path(args[0])`, which is the **local** JVM and filesystem, designated by the URI `file://`.

When you give the arguments to `hadoop jar`, it knows that it should read from HDFS, which is specified in an XML file for your Hadoop configurations, and looks for the input at URI `hdfs://`.

For reference, `ls -l /` compared to `hdfs dfs -ls /` are very different outputs. The former doesn't have the specified path.

Sidenote: The default HDFS path is using `file://`, **but** Cloudera Quickstart changes this for you.